# How do I use the googleapis node package in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I am using Ember 3.10 and made a fresh project and did `npm i googleapis`. I tried using `ember-auto-import` and `ember-cli-es6-transform` but neither work. All I want is for this to work:

```
import { google } from 'googleapis';
```

I did notice that Google pre-builds the package (`googleapis/build/src/...`). Does this mean I can just do `app.import(node_modules/googleapis/...)` in my `ember-cli-build.js` file? Any clues or tips? Am I supposed to even use the node package?

Comment: The way you are doing it should work correctly without any extra configuration, if you are using ember-auto-import and following the instructions correctly on their README.  What errors are you seeing?

Comment: So I dug into it more, and it looks like you may be experiencing something similar to this: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-nodejs/issues/150

Answer (score 0):

1 . You can try downloading the external/third-party JavaScript file and paste it under `app-name/vendor/ext-js-file-name.js`

2 . Use `app.import('vendor/ext-js-file-name.js');` to include it in the build

3 . Then include `ember-auto-import` addon

Comment: Hmm following these three steps, I'm getting `Uncaught Error: Could not find module 'googleapis'` when I do:

`import { google } from 'googleapis';`

Comment: on using `ember-auto-import` addon, you don't need to do `import { google } from 'googleapis';`

Comment: Wait then how do I use?
Step 2 from docs say - "just import it from your Ember app code:
`import { capitalize } from 'lodash-es';`
There is no step two. Works from both app code and test code."